# Angular JS - Filter object keys by key names

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have object persons

```
persons = {
    name : 'Thomas M',
    username : 'mthomas',
    company : 'XYZ',
    email : 'tom@xyz.com'
    city : 'Philadelphia',
    country : 'USA'
};
```

is there any to filter that object by key name i.e if i filter by the keyword - name, it should display 
name
username

AngularJS filter works on value but on key value.

Comment: Plunker link- https://plnkr.co/edit/7NEruSOtUjIWS5ceKe36?p=preview for reference which I am currently working and trying different options to find solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot AWolf for your answer.

I have found simple way to filter based on key.

Please find the fiddle below for reference and let me know your comments

```
        <body>
      <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as mainCtrl">
        current filter:
        <input ng-model="field" ng-change="mainCtrl.cur" />
        <div ng-repeat="x in keys | filter:field">
          <p>{{x}} :
            <input readonly="" type="text" ng-model="person[x]" class="person" />
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>

    angular.module('myApp', [])
      .controller('myCtrl', function MainController($scope) {
        $scope.person = {
          name: 'Thomas M',
          username: 'mthomas',
          company: 'XYZ',
          email: 'tom@xyz.com',
          city: 'Philadelphia',
          country: 'USA'
        };

        $scope.keys = Object.keys($scope.person);



      });

    /* Styles go here */

    .person {
      border: none
    }
```

Thanks
Sai

Comment: Good solution. You could also create a custom filter but your way is also OK. I only don't like your ng-repeat markup for key iteration. It's working but I think `(key, value)` ng-repeat syntax is easier to use/read. Please have a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xz7ykw4z/).

Comment: looks great.. thanks AWolf :) .. vote coming for you :)

Answer (score 2):

You could create a for-loop that's iterating over the object and do a check if the property needs to be picked.

If you don't like to code it you could use [underscore.pick](http://underscorejs.org/#pick) for this.

Please have a look at the demo below or in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/19pfqkyw/).

```js
angular.module('demoApp', [])
  .controller('mainController', MainController);

function MainController() {
  var vm = this;

  var person = {
    name: 'Thomas M',
    username: 'mthomas',
    company: 'XYZ',
    email: 'tom@xyz.com',
    city: 'Philadelphia',
    country: 'USA'
  };

  vm.curFilter = 'name, username';

  vm.applyFilter = function() {
    var filterData = vm.curFilter
      .replace(/\s/g, '').split(',');
    vm.filteredPerson = pick(person, filterData);
  };

  vm.applyFilter(); // initial apply

  function pick(obj) {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj),
      args = arguments[1] instanceof Array ? arguments[1] : [].slice.apply(arguments),
      key = '',
      picked = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      key = keys[i];
      //console.log(key, args, args.indexOf(key));
      if (args.indexOf(key) !== -1) {
        picked[key] = obj[key];
      }
    }

    return picked;
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainController as mainCtrl">
  current filter:
  <input ng-model="mainCtrl.curFilter" ng-change="mainCtrl.applyFilter()">
  <pre>
{{mainCtrl.filteredPerson | json : 2}}
</pre>
</div>
```